# STM32F4 Discovery Board Control Register Value Problem

Tags: stm32

In Atollic TrueSTUDIO I open an empty project without any settings.

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4_discovery.h"

int main(void)
{
  while (1)
  {

  }
}

void EVAL_AUDIO_TransferComplete_CallBack(uint32_t pBuffer, uint32_t Size){
  /* TODO, implement your code here */
  return;
}

uint16_t EVAL_AUDIO_GetSampleCallBack(void){
  /* TODO, implement your code here */
  return -1;
}
```

and I observe the values in the CR register.

[image]

As seen in the photo it comes full of many bits. Even both HSE and HSI are active. Why? How?

I was just expecting HSI to be active because the reset value of this register is 0x83.

I also cannot reset the values of the bits when I add the RCC->CR=0x83; code to the program. Where am I making a mistake? (I adding the RCC->CR=0x83; code to the top of the while.)

Why are these settings pre-defined? Why doesn't the register change when I assign a value?

---

STM32F407xx RCC Register from Reference Manual:

[image: STM32F407xx RCC Register from Reference Manual]

Answer (score 1):

`Main()` is not where the chip boots.
Find the reset interrupt handler. In there you will find it calls `SystemInit`, which does some basic setup and clocks for you.